# How to shutdown a computer remotely from outside LAN?

Tags: networking, lan, shutdown, remote, remote-shutdown

I would like to be able to shutdown or restart a computer on a remote network. If it were on my local area network, I would use the `shutdown -i command`. How can I do this remotely? I cannot use Remote Desktop Connection. The network has a static IP address.

Comment: Probably because you didn't provide any specifics. We can assume the target machine is a Windows host but it would be nice to have the details. Target machine? Source machine? What type of connection do you have to the target machine? Do you have Administrator or equivalent credentials for the target machine?

Comment: If you could easily shutdown a computer from outside your network, that would wreak havoc for anyone on the Internet. ;)  Firewalls and network security in general, are meant to stop this exact type of thing.  You'll need to make a plan while you have access to the LAN, and probably install something within the LAN to communicate (securely) with from the outside, and use it to launch commands.  What this can/should be for you is impossible to answer, since as @joeqwerty points out in his comment, you haven't given us enough info.

Answer (score 1):

To shutdown remote machine

```
shutdown -s -f -m \\remotecomputername
```

To restart remote machine

```
shutdown -r -f -m \\remotecomputername
```

If you make this mistake you have 30 seconds to cancel the Windows shutdown with the -a switch.

-a  Is for abort.  This it only works during the time-out period

```
shutdown -a
```